# Messages from syslogd, what do they mean and what do I do?

Tags: kernel, opensuse, syslog

Recently, these messages started popping up straight into my prompt when I'm connected to the OpenSUSE system in question via PuTTY:

```
Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:04:03 ...
 kernel:[ 6177.851012] EIP: [<75c0234e>] 0x75c0234e SS:ESP 0068:f324dde1

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020] Process sh (pid: 6245, ti=f2bee000 task=f32fd2b0 task.ti=f2bee000)

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020] Stack:

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020] Inexact backtrace:

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020]

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020] Code:  Bad EIP value.

Message from syslogd@host at Aug  5 11:15:01 ...
 kernel:[ 6836.654020] EIP: [<75c0234e>] 0x75c0234e SS:ESP 0068:f2befead
```

I know some very basic stuff about Linux but this catches me off guard. What does this mean? How do I troubleshoot?

**edit** Turns out the system is actually unreachable now, while it does reply to ping I cannot connect via SSH to it. Is there anything I can do physically on the machine?

Answer (score 7):

These messages look like the kernel was having a [kernel panic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic). It was basically crashing. There's little you can do if the system is unstable/crashing.

Typically these types of messages will show up on the console. There you can use the command `dmesg -n 1` to disable them from being printed, since they can get a little annoying when they're benign.

*excerpt from [`dmesg` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dmesg.1.html)*

```
-n level
       Set  the  level  at  which  logging  of messages is done to the 
       console.  For example, -n 1 prevents all messages, except panic
       messages, from appearing on the console.  All levels of messages
       are still written to /proc/kmsg,  so syslogd(8)  can  still be used 
       to control exactly where kernel messages appear.  When the -n option 
       is used, dmesg will not print or clear the kernel ring buffer.
```

#### Bad EIP Value

This error often always means you're having some type of failure of your hardware, often your RAM. I would enlist something like [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to verify that the RAM is functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how I can ignore these messages, but since they are making the system crash and become unreachable via SSH I would need to try a solution. Should I try booting an older kernel in GRUB and see if the problem goes away? Should I try updating OpenSUSE via zypper?

Comment: I would try rebooting with an older Kernel 1st. Perhaps an update went south on you. But it may be hardware that's failing, so I'd look to run something like memtest86+.

Comment: If it helps, I saw on the physical screen attached to the server that I am getting an error saying "Bad EIP value". I can't get a new prompt by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 or whatever the combination is, I just get the same error. Rebooting the system fixes the issue temporarily, I'm running an older kernel now. Any ideas on how to proceed with troubleshooting?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 - Bad EIP Values typically mean RAM is failing. Sounds like you might be having a hardware problem.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 - see updates, sounds like RAM is failing.

Comment: If you have console access, there are some [magic keyboard combinations with the SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) you can use to collect more information. Maybe install something like `atop` to get snapshots you can examine after a crash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing it on a Raspberry Pi Zero only when running a particular fork of cgminer (vt_hoang).  It usually runs about 2 days and crashes the system.  The same cgminer also crashes a different Pi.  I hadn't noticed messages to stderr before, I'd just set logging to be persistent across reboots and was looking at journalctl output.  I need to try again with valgrind and gdb.

But the error message is just that, making them shut up isn't going to fix the underlying problem.  A different kernel might act differently, but it can also be some software you're running.  It isn't necessarily a hardware problem.